# По каким правилам происходит привязка данных в контроллере?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, binding, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Недавно столкнулся с непонятным для меня поведением привязки данных в контроллере.

В представлении, некоторые HTML элементы ввода данных (select, input, etc.) создавались динамически и их имена соответствовали именам свойств модели. На данном этапе все работало отлично. Далее, были добавлены некоторые элементы, имена которых ошибочно содержали префикс `Person`, что соответствует имени класса модели. С этого момента в контроллере все свойства, которые ранее были доступны, стали `null` или значениями по-умолчанию, а добавленные элементы с префиксом имени класса наоборот стали доступны. При удалении префикса с именем класса все свойства модели стали доступными.

Сам контроллер не представляет из себя ничего необычного:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,FirstName,LastName,...")] Person person) {

    if (ModelState.IsValid) {

        _context.Add(person);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(person);
}
```

Само представление:

```
@model ProjectName.Models.Person
...
<form asp-action="Create">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <!-- Создает input элемент с именем "FirstName" -->
        <input asp-for="FirstName" />
        <!-- Этот элемент был добавлен с ошибочным префиксом. -->
        <!-- При таком имени элемента в контроллере доступно только свойство LastName. -->
        <input name="Person.LastName" type="text" />
        <!-- А с таким именем всё нормально, что логично. -->
        <input name="LastName" type="text" />
    </div>
</form>
```

---

В связи с чем возникает вопрос: *имеется ли какая-либо информация/документация, которая бы разъясняла методы/способы/приоритеты связывания данных?* Интересует в частности роль имён HTML-элементов ввода данных в связывании данных и их приоритет друг перед другом, как в приведенном выше примере.

Comment: Я знаю про похожие проблемы (вот [топик](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2278056/5752652) из закладок) только там с ViewBag'ом сложности. И вообще, вопрос шикарный, сам не отказался бы почитать в структурированном виде подробный ответ.

Comment: @A_K спасибо большое за ссылочку. Ещё нигде не сталкивался в документации о недопустимости использования одинаковых имён свойств модели и "ключей" ViewBug/ViewData. Интересует лишь было ли это исправлено в ASP.Net Core.