# Как сериализовать JavaScript объект в GET параметры?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, url, asp.net-core, сериализация

Имеется объект:

```
var obj = {
  prop1: "str",
  prop2: 5,
  arr: [{
    prop1: "str",
    prop2: false
  }]
};
```

Его необходимо преобразовать в строку GET параметров URL для использования в ASP.Net Core (к примеру передачи параметров поиска и фильтрации GET контроллеру) следующего вида:
`prop1=str&prop2=5&arr[0].prop1=str&arr[0].prop2=false`
, то есть для массивов должен указываться индекс, а свойства объектов должны указываться через точку. Структура объекта строго не установлена, что означает возможное наличие вложенных массивов и объектов в разных вариациях. Пробовал так:

JSON.stringify(obj)

`"{"prop1":"str","prop2":5,"arr":[{"prop1":"str","prop2":false}]}"`

jQuery.param(obj)

encoded `prop1=str&prop2=5&arr%5B0%5D%5Bprop1%5D=str&arr%5B0%5D%5Bprop2%5D=false`
decoded `prop1=str&prop2=5&arr[0][prop1]=str&arr[0][prop2]=false`

Как видно, jQuery.param делает почти то, что нужно, но всё-таки не то.
Каким образом сериализовать объект к требуемому виду?

#### Ссылки по теме

- [Передача данных в контроллер](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/5.2.php)
- [По каким правилам происходит привязка данных в контроллере?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/749309/182750)
- [Expression names in ASP.Net views](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.2#expression-names)

Comment: Какой-то нестандартный формат вы хотите. Вы уверены в нем?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko как раз таки стандартный формат для ASP.Net

Comment: А может лучше такие данные передавать через POST?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov это конечно на много проще, но в этом случае будет невозможно добавить поисковый запрос в закладки и скорее всего с кэшированием будут проблемы, ну и это нарушает CRUD принцип.

Comment: jQuery делает правильно.

Comment: @Qwertiy ASP.Net контроллер не понимает GET аргументы массивов в URL без явного указания индекса.

Comment: @XelaNimed, там указан индекс.

Comment: @Qwertiy извиняюсь... Свойство массива указано в квадратных, а должно через точку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как ничего толкового не нашёл, то для себя решил проблему следующей функцией:

```
function getUrlPairs(obj) {

    var getType = obj => obj === undefined ? 'undefined' : (obj === null ? 'null' : obj.constructor.name),
        simple = (path, val) => path + '=' + val,
        simpleEnc = (path, val) => simple(path, encodeURIComponent(val)),
        typeFunc = {
          null: simple,
          undefined: (path, val) => simple(path, ''),
          Number: simple,
          Boolean: simple,
          String: simpleEnc,
          RegExp: simpleEnc,
          Date: (path, val) => simpleEnc(path, val.toJSON()),
          Object: (path, val, dot = '.') => iterate(val, path + dot, name => name),
          Array: (path, val) => iterate(val, path, name => '[' + name + ']')
      },
      pairs = [],
      type = getType(obj);

    function iterate(obj, prefix, wrap) {
        for (const[name, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
            const call = typeFunc[getType(val)];
            const tmp = call && call(prefix + wrap(name), val);
            call && tmp && pairs.push(tmp);
        }
    }

    typeFunc[type] && typeFunc[type]('', obj, '');

    return pairs;
}
```

Ниже пример использования и тест сериализации объекта:

```js
var obj = {
    dirty: "&%[]?",
    nullable: null,
    undef: undefined,
    numberProp: 123,
    now: new Date(),
    boolProp: true,
    obj: {
      objProp1: "objStr",
      objProp2: false,
     nullable: null,
      objInObj: {
       aa:"aa",
        bb: true
      }
    },
    arr: [{
        regexProp: new RegExp('^[a-z0-9]+$', 'i'),
        arrProp12: 321,
        arrProp13: true,
        arrProp14: {
          a: "absdefg",
          b: true
        }
      },
      {
        arrProp21: "rts",
        arrProp22: 987,
        arrProp23: false
      },
      ["arrInArr1", "arrInArr2"],
      [{test:"str"}],
      null,
     new Date()
    ]
  };
  
  function getUrlPairs(obj) {

    var getType = obj => obj === undefined ? 'undefined' : (obj === null ? 'null' : obj.constructor.name),
        simple = (path, val) => path + '=' + val,
        simpleEnc = (path, val) => simple(path, encodeURIComponent(val)),
        typeFunc = {
          null: simple,
          undefined: (path, val) => simple(path, ''),
          Number: simple,
          Boolean: simple,
          String: simpleEnc,
          RegExp: simpleEnc,
          Date: (path, val) => simpleEnc(path, val.toJSON()),
          Object: (path, val, dot = '.') => iterate(val, path + dot, name => name),
          Array: (path, val) => iterate(val, path, name => '[' + name + ']')
      },
      pairs = [],
      type = getType(obj);

    function iterate(obj, prefix, wrap) {
        for (const[name, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
            const call = typeFunc[getType(val)];
            const tmp = call && call(prefix + wrap(name), val);
            call && tmp && pairs.push(tmp);
        }
    }

    typeFunc[type] && typeFunc[type]('', obj, '');

    return pairs;
}

var res = getUrlPairs(obj);

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = 
res.join("\n") 
+ "\n\n" 
+ res.join("&");
```

```css
textarea {
    width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="20" id="output"></textarea>
```

Comment: Что-то я экранирования нигде не вижу...

Comment: @Qwertiy ну как-же... `var encode = str => encodeURIComponent(str);`

Answer (score -1):

создайте переменную `obj="str&prop2=5&arr[0].prop1=str&arr[0].prop2=false"`  и передавайте

Comment: Вопрос как раз о том, как автоматически её создать.

Comment: обычная конкатенация строк: obj=str.toString()+"&"+prop2.toStrong()+"=5&"..... и так  завелась и поехала.

Comment: Которая сразу же лишает возможности использовать символ & в значениях. Нельзя так делать, да и просто неуклюже выглядит

Comment: сказал чувак который таким изощренным способом хочет передать) . Можно любым знаком поменять например знаком -, а на стороне сервера 
" - " подменять на &.

Comment: А это уже вопиющая безграмотность, раз вы даже про стандартное экранирование не в курсе